# When building gradle project I get an error: dependencies (implementation) not found, and I can't figure out why?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, dependencies, classnotfoundexception, implementation

I got this assignment and received a project which has an implementation for a front-end and the assignment is to connect it with my own back-end implementation. It's a gradle project that uses Angular to connect the back- and the front-end. Now that I try to run/build the project I receive some errors which seem to come from not being able to find certain dependencies. However I don't know why and how to fix it, can anyone help me out?

This is the error:

```
mrt. 30, 2023 11:04:39 A.M. org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlFeature configure
WARNING: JAXBContext implementation could not be found. WADL feature is disabled.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler$Context
        at myproject.App.createStatefulContext(App.java:36)
        at myproject.App.main(App.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 2 more
```

I tried to find info about the dependencies, maybe they turn out to be out-dated or something, but could not find such a thing...

Comment: have you tried adding a dependency to that lib/class?

Comment: @Stultuske it should find all its dependencies via the build.gradle file in my api folder. Here all dependencies are listed which are needed for the project. When I look at this file it includes the org.eclipse.jetty.server dependency. So, I don't understand why it can not be found